# Regex, how to get the values within { { } brackets?

Tags: regex, python3

I'm new to regex, just trying to get the values between curly braces { } but landed with no luck. Could anyone please help me here? This is in python BTW and i need to open a text file and split based on the curly braces.

the data is similar to this #242424##{FFFFF}{2{GGFFFGF}{BBBBB}}{GGGG}

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What result do you expect? What to do with nested curly braces? [Edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1743501/edit) and add expected reult and what you've tried.

Comment: Without going into too much detail, I'd suggest using Perl or Python using the `regex` lib so you could use this https://regex101.com/r/LZZglJ/1 `{((?:[^{}]++|(?R))*)}` to capture the outer `{ }`'s contents into an an array that you can recursively run it on it's contents. But it's more complex than that and it's not a simple answer.

Answer (score 1):

[this regexp](https://regex101.com/r/aCIo9N/1) will give you the text inside curly brackets.

Now, your question is not clear or specific, since you have nested brackets. Please **give example about what your expected output should be**.

And post code of what you have, a complete working piece of code.

Anyways, regexp returns 4 groups:

```
#242424##{FFFFF}{2{GGFFFGF}{BBBBB}}{GGGG}
           --1     --2      --3     --4

==> 

1   FFFFF
2   GGFFFGF
3   BBBBB
4   GGGG
```